# Output of an implementation algorithm over graph

Tags: python

This code is some operations on graphs, basically instructions are given on input like the following:

```
class NodoArvore:
    def __init__(self, chave=None, esquerda=None, direita=None):
        self.chave = chave
        self.esquerda = esquerda
        self.direita = direita

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s <- %s -> %s' % (self.esquerda and self.esquerda.chave,
                                    self.chave,
                                    self.direita and self.direita.chave)

raiz = NodoArvore(40)

raiz.esquerda = NodoArvore(20)
raiz.direita  = NodoArvore(60)

raiz.direita.esquerda  = NodoArvore(50)
raiz.direita.direita   = NodoArvore(70)
raiz.esquerda.esquerda = NodoArvore(10)
raiz.esquerda.direita  = NodoArvore(30)
```

Comment: What do you need ? is it simply the method to count vertices, edges and weights ?  BTW `v in graph.keys()` is very inefficient because it does a sequential search. `v in graph` does the same thing instantly using hash indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your functions a little and added the final computations.  Also I used dictionaries instead of lists for the edges/weights to make the graph alterations easier to implement (and more efficient):

```
graph    = dict()
directed = True

def add_node(v):
    if v in graph: return print(v, "is already part of the graph")
    graph[v] = dict()

def add_edge(v1,v2,weight):
    if v1 not in graph or v2 not in graph: 
        return print(v1,"or",v2,"not part of the graph")
    if v2 in graph[v1]:
        return print((v1,v2),"already part of the graph")
    graph[v1][v2] = weight
    if not directed: graph[v2][v1] = weight
        
def delete_edge(v1,v2):
    if v1 not in graph or v2 not in graph[v1]: 
        return print((v1,v2),"not part of the graph")
    graph[v1].pop(V2)
    if not directed: graph[v2].pop(V1)

def delete_node(v):
    if v not in graph: return print(v,"not part of the graph")        
    for e in graph.values():
        if v in e: e.pop(v)
    graph.pop(v)

def count_edges():
    return sum(map(len,graph.values()))//[2,1][directed]

def count_weights():
    return sum(w for e in graph.values() for w in e.values())/[2,1][directed]
```

Usage:

```
no_operations = int(input("Enter number of operations: "))

for _ in range(no_operations):
    command = input("Enter command: ")
    oper,v1,v2, weight,*_ = command.split(" ") + ["",""]
    if   oper == 'IV': add_node(v1)
    elif oper == 'IA': add_edge(v1,v2,float(weight))
    elif oper == 'RV': delete_node(v1)
    elif oper == 'RA': delete_edge(v1,v2)
    else:print("Invalid command")

nodeCount = len(graph)
edgeCount = count_edges()
weights   = count_weights()

print(nodeCount,"vertex(s),",edgeCount,"edge(s) and total weight",weights)

print(graph)
```

Sample run:

```
Enter number of operations: 4
Enter command: IV A
Enter command: IA B A 1
not part of the graph
Enter command: IV B
Enter command: IA A B 2
2 vertex(s), 1 edge(s) and total weight 2.0
{'A': {'B': 2.0}, 'B': {'A': 2.0}}
```

...

```
# directed graph:

Enter number of operations: 14
Enter command: IV A
Enter command: IV B
Enter command: IV C
Enter command: IV D
Enter command: IA A B 0.1
Enter command: IA A C 0.2
Enter command: IA B A 0.3
Enter command: IA B C 0.4
Enter command: IA C A 0.5
Enter command: IA C B 0.6
Enter command: IV D
D is already part of the graph
Enter command: IV E
Enter command: IA D E -10
Enter command: RV A
4 vertex(s), 3 edge(s) and total weight -9.0
{'B': {'C': 0.4}, 'C': {'B': 0.6}, 'D': {'E': -10.0}, 'E': {}}
```

Comment: check the code alignement, probably a copy paste issue.

Comment: `IA TO C 0.2` is invalid, `IA A B 0.1` and `IA B A 0.3` redefine the same edge.  `IA B C 0.4` and `IA C B 0.6` also  redefine the same edge.  `IV D` and `IV A` are  already in graph, `IA D E -10` is not in the graph (E).  This sequence gives me `3 vertex(s), 1 edge(s) and total weight 0.4`.  Run it interactively, you should see what's happening as you go.

Comment: After guessing and fixing your sequence, I came to the same numbers given that the only edges that remain are B-C:0.4 and D-E:-10.  (`RV A` removed A-B:0.1 and A-C:0.2).  The duplicate edge definitions don't update the weights (you could change that by removing the 2nd condition in `add_edge` if needed)

Comment: Making this a directed graph (allowing different weights depending on direction) would require changing all the functions.  Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, with the directed graph, the sequence results in the expected counts: `4 vertex(s), 3 edge(s) and total weight -9.0`.  I made the change in my answer to support directed graph mode (variable at the beginning).

Comment: You'll need to count vertices associated with both sides of each edge and pick the one from the vertex with the lowest count.  You could use the Counter class (from collections) to do this: `min(Counter(v for a,e in graph.items() for b in e.values() for v in (a,b)).values())`

Comment: Sure, I'll look at it when I have minute